# Cant access orders after migration using cart 2 cart

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, backend

Yesterday i used cart 2 cart to migrate all my orders and customers from my oscommerce site to my magento site All the orders and customers appear is the appropriate grids. However when i click into my orders i get this error

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php on line 750

The line it is talking about is this

```
if (!$this->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->canEdit()) {
    return false;
}
```

in the public function canEdit

What is causing this error? and how can i fix it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already bumped into this, it's caused by the fact that your orders don't use a standard payment method (defined in Magento), probably because they come from OsCommerce. Look up in your OsCommerce database for the title of the payment method, and try to re-create the same payment method in Magento (or modify the title of an already existing method such as `checkmo` but it's not advisable).

Comment: I just went into my database for the source store (osCommerce), went into the orders made and saw the payment method Credit Card, and when i check on the magento back end there is a payment method with the name Credit Card. What table in my magento database should i look in to see orders?

Comment: mostly `sales_flat_quote`,`sales_flat_quote_payment`, `sales_flat_order`,`sales_flat_order_payment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Magento in my opinion.
To view the order details, Magento needs to have the payment method instance used to place the order active in the current instance.
So for example if for order 100001 payment method `PaymentX` was used, then you need a payment method class associated to `PaymentX` that extends the class `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` to be accessible to Magento.

I assume you did not migrate the payment methods, because that might be impossible since the 2 platforms are not compatible.

A possible (but not very easy) way of solving this is to create dummy payment method models for all the payments you had in the oscommerce website.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) on how to create a payment module.

Good luck.